# how to upload and read a file with nodejs / express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, pug

there are all kinds of posts about this, but I'm still not getting it. 
I want to upload a *.csv and read and process its contents.

my jade file is this

```
//views/import.jade
extends layout
block content
h1= title
form(action="/import", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(type="file", name="ufile")
    input(type="submit", name="Upload")
```

--

I changed the code, but req.files is undefined

```
//routes/index.js

/* import page. */
router.get('/blah', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('import', { title: 'Import Data' });
});

router.post('/import', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Which middleware do you use with express to handle file upload ? What is at app.js line 30 ?

Comment: you're sending your form with method POST but declaring a GET route. The first step is to change your route to ```router.post('/import'...``` and try again.

Comment: changed the code ... no dice.

Comment: are you using the bodyparser middleware?

Comment: I am not using bodyparser middleware. Was not even aware of its necessity. Will go and research. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Convert the uploaded file in to string, using

> toString('utf8')

you can than make any operation on string like convert it to json using [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) package

Here is the sample code for uploading csv and than convert to json-

```
/* csv to json */

const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  upload = require("express-fileupload"),
  csvtojson = require("csvtojson");

let csvData = "test";
app.use(upload());

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/file", (req, res) => {
/** convert req buffer into csv string , 
*   "csvfile" is the name of my file given at name attribute in input tag */
  csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
  return csvtojson().fromString(csvData).then(json => 
    {return res.status(201).json({csv:csvData, json:json})})
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){
  console.log('Your node js server is running');
});
```

working example- [csvjsonapi](https://csvjsonapi.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: this is exactly what i am trying to do, but for some reason it isn't working for me. The toString() method on the buffer object just returns empty. I tried your working example and it worked fine with the same file so i really dont know why it would work here but not on my code, im accessing req.files.[name].data and it returns the buffer, adding the toString() method doesnt return the expected string. IS there a way to feed the raw data directly into csvtojson?

Answer (score 5):

Hope this solves your question, this is my method to multiple upload file:

Nodejs :

```
router.post('/upload', function(req , res) {
    var multiparty = require('multiparty');
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    var fs = require('fs');
    
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {  
        var imgArray = files.imatges;
    
    
        for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            var newPath = './public/uploads/'+fields.imgName+'/';
            var singleImg = imgArray[i];
            newPath+= singleImg.originalFilename;
            readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath);           
        }
        res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
    
    });
    
    function readAndWriteFile(singleImg, newPath) {
    
            fs.readFile(singleImg.path , function(err,data) {
                fs.writeFile(newPath,data, function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);
                    console.log('Fitxer: '+singleImg.originalFilename +' - '+ newPath);
                })
            })
    }
})
```

Make sure your form tag has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

I hope this gives you a hand ;)

Comment: Thanx @TirthrajBarot ;) I'm just a beginner I try to do my best :P